# magic function %hist not found Mac OSX

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I'm using ipython on Mac OS X Snow leopard and for some reason I get an error when I use the hist magic function, even when giving it as %hist.  When I give `hist` I get a python `NameError` and when I give `%hist` I get an ipython error `ERROR: Magic function 'hist' not found.`

I can see the history file in the .ipython folder, and it's up-to-date.  I have readline correctly installed (tab completion works), and up-arrow command cycling also works.  The hist function also works on my PC.

Has anyone else seen this problem?  I have tried Googling the error message, but nothing came up.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of IPython are you using?

According to the [interactive manual](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/tutorial.html), "As of the 0.11 version of IPython, some of the features and APIs described in this section have been deprecated or are broken. Our plan is to continue to support these features, but they need to be updated to take advantage of recent API changes. Furthermore, this section of the documentation need to be updated to reflect all of these changes."

Comment: %hist is still in 0.11, however.

Comment: I'm using v 0.11 so %hist should work as Thomas K points out.

Comment: Thomas, it's still in 0.11, but is it still working? The manual says that it may be broken. Hassantm, maybe you can try reverting to an earlier version and see if that works.